# Selecionar vários registros usando uma condição jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela que possui algumas colunas em branco, quero selecionar apenas as as linhas cujo conteúdo está completo. No meu exemplo está selecionando todas, não está respeitando o conteúdo.

```js
    $("#selectAllOS").click(function () {

        if ($('#selectAllOS').is(':checked')) {

            $.each($("#gridOS tbody tr"), function (index, value) {
                //conteúdo da coluna 3
                var conteudo = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
                var check = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
                if (conteudo !== "") {
                    //checkbox apenas nas colunas com o conteúdo completo
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
                } 
            });

        } else {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
        }

    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<table id="gridOS" border="1" style="width:100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllOS" name="selectAllOS" /></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Danfe</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="check-os" type="checkbox" data-action="check" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>8787878787878</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="check-os" type="checkbox" data-action="check" value="2" /></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="check-os" type="checkbox" data-action="check" value="3" /></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>8787878787878</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Se queres selecionar as colunas, porque estás a fazer `$.each` de `tr`?
Acho que queres as linhas completas, não?

Comment: @Aurium, estou fazendo $.each de tr porque ao click em selectAllOS, eu estou percorrendo toda a tabela por isso eu pego o conteúdo para saber se aquela determinada linha tem alguma coisa na coluna 3

Comment: @Aurium, veja que selectAllOS está no <thead> da tabela, ele serve para seleciona tudo de uma única vez

Comment: @Aurium, postei a solução, deu trabalho mais deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi fazer desta forma, que funciona muito bem por sinal.

```js
          $("#selectAllOS").click(function () {

            if ($('#selectAllOS').is(':checked')) {

                $.each($("#gridOS tbody tr"), function (index, value) {
                    //conteúdo da coluna 3
                    var conteudo = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html();
                    //conteúdo da linha atual
                    var check = $(this).find('td:eq(0) :input');

                    if (conteudo !== "") {
                        console.log(index);
                        //checkbox apenas nas colunas com o conteúdo completo
                        $(check).prop("checked", true);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
            }

        });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<table id="gridOS" border="1" style="width:100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllOS" name="selectAllOS" /></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Danfe</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="check-os" type="checkbox" data-action="check" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>8787878787878</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="check-os" type="checkbox" data-action="check" value="2" /></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input class="check-os" type="checkbox" data-action="check" value="3" /></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>8787878787878</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```